# all relative URLs get converted into absolute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

This issue exists in Chrome and Firefox but not IE.

I have an angular app.
Once a certain view is loaded, all the xhr requests made with relative paths get converted into requests with absolute path.

Example:

I navigate to `http://example.com/foo/#/bar`

in Chrome dev tools I type:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "ping", true);//or "./ping"
xhr.send();
```

The result is a 404 error and the network tab shows that the request was made to `http://example.com/ping` instead of `http://example.com/foo/ping`.

What can possibly cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a rogue `<base href="/">` tag.